# Complex views in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

In the MVC model, where does the view differentiate between the model when the views are sufficiently complex?

My question arises from my attempt to develop a desktop application with a Canvas **view**. The user has a click mode (e.g. select, add object A, add object B, add object C, etc.). When performing actions, this changes data in the **model**. The state of the **model** can later be saved to a file via another **view** control.

When starting the project, I attempted to encapsulate as much of the Canvas-specific state as possible into the Canvas **view**. However as I attempt to fit the MVC pattern, it seems as though most of it belongs in the **model**.

I feel as though the Canvas class is complex enough to contain its own state, which is where my confusion arises. It contains the location of several types of objects on the Canvas. Where does the boundary lie between view data and model data? Or is this a case where there is MVC within an MVC (i.e. M V(MVC) C)?

Comment: To extend the question: If I have a click mode for the canvas as described above that will not be stored persistently, should that ever be conveyed to the model or the controller?

Comment: I have chosen MVVM after looking into some patterns. It seems to be exactly what I needed. The ViewModels hold data specific to the views or controls, that will never be saved but still need to be bound to by the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have chosen MVVM after looking into some patterns. It seems to be exactly what I needed. The ViewModels hold data specific to the views or controls, that will never be saved but still need to be bound to by the UI.